# How to insert value which is selected from another table with separate value at same time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wont to add selected values from `Person` table and my own values (`@EmpId`, `GETDATE()`) to `EmployeeDeleteLog` table at the same time.

This is the `EmployeeDeleteLog` table:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeDeleteLog
(
    IDdeleted int,
    FirstName varchar(50) ,
    LastName varchar(100),
    DeleteDate date,
    Email varchar(100),
    Fax varchar(12),
    PostBox varchar(6),
    Street varchar(60),
    City varchar(60),
    Province varchar(60),
    Country varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

This is the `Person` table:

```
create table Person
(
    IdNo int primary key identity NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) ,
    LastName varchar(100),
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
    Nationality varchar(50),
    Email varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    Fax varchar(12) UNIQUE,
    PostBox varchar(6),
    Street varchar(60),
    City varchar(60),
    Province varchar(60),
    Country varchar(100) NOT NULL    
);
```

In here I want to do this kind of thing:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog 
VALUES(@EmpID,
       (SELECT FirstName FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT LastName FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       GETDATE(),
       (SELECT Email FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT Fax FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT PostBox FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT Street FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT City FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT Province FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID),
       (SELECT Country FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpID) )
```

Tell me possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a single select instead of specifying using Values

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog 
(
    IDdeleted,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    DeleteDate,
    Email,
    Fax,
    PostBox,
    Street,
    City,
    Province,
    Country
)
SELECT
    IDdeleted = IdNo,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    DeleteDate = GETDATE(),
    Email,
    Fax,
    PostBox,
    Street,
    City,
    Province,
    Country
    FROM Person 
        WHERE IdNo=@EmpID
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. It works. But i have another problem here. above code is part of the full code. using above code when i have inserted data into the  "EmployeeDeleteLog" table. but in "EmployeeDeleteLog" table "IDdeleted" and "DeleteDate" colums has data. other all colums has "NULL"  value.

Comment: This is FULL CODE, it is stored procedure:

Comment: That's because the values are null in the source

Comment: No , Data is available in Person table

Comment: Then this should work. Please make sure you don't have any triggers or something like that which  clears the data from those columns

Comment: How can i send you my FULL CODE? there is no any trigger or some thing like that.

Comment: Try sqlfiddle.com you can create your tables there and share the url in the question

Comment: I have ask my new quection with full code on Stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981170/columns-which-i-inserted-that-selected-values-from-another-table-are-null-why

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Insert into the table before deleting.. otherwise you won't get records

Comment: Looking at your code, this should work, I wonder whether there is something else that's giving you the wrong results

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with MySQL, below should be a simpler solution.

```
insert into EmployeeDeleteLog select @EmpID,FirstName,LastName,now(),Email,Fax,PostBox,Street,City,Province,Country from Person where IdNo=@EmpID;
```

*Note: Replace @EmpID with required ID*

Comment: no i am working with MS SQL server. thanks for your answer. but in here i have another problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981170/columns-which-i-inserted-that-selected-values-from-another-table-are-null-why