# Columns which i inserted that selected values from another table are null. why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have insert values which is selected from another table and my own values into the table. In the Table, columns which I inserted my own values are inserted. but columns which I inserted that selected values from another table are `null`. Why?

I have inserted data into the "EmployeeDeleteLog" table, but in "`EmployeeDeleteLog`" table "`IDdeleted`" and "`DeleteDate`" columns has data. other all columns has "`NULL`" value.

1.Part 1

```
create table Person
(
    IdNo int primary key identity NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(50) ,
    LastName varchar(100),
    Gender char(1) NOT NULL,
    Nationality varchar(50),
    Email varchar(100) UNIQUE,
    Fax varchar(12) UNIQUE,
    PostBox varchar(6),
    Street varchar(60),
    City varchar(60),
    Province varchar(60),
    Country varchar(100) NOT NULL    
);

CREATE TABLE EmployeeDeleteLog(
    IDdeleted int,
    FirstName varchar(50) ,
    LastName varchar(100),
    DeleteDate date,
    Email varchar(100),
    Fax varchar(12),
    PostBox varchar(6),
    Street varchar(60),
    City varchar(60),
    Province varchar(60),
    Country varchar(100)
)
```

2.Part 2

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[countIDs] (@EmpID AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myCount AS INT

    SELECT @myCount = COUNT(IdNo)
    FROM Person
    WHERE IdNo = @EmpID

    RETURN @myCount
END
```

3.Part 3

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Employee_Delete](@EmpID int)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

    IF [dbo].[countIDs](@EmpID) <> 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('ID does not exist', 1, 1)
        RETURN 0
    END



        --check to see if update occured 
        --and return status
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog(IDdeleted,
                                            FirstName,
                                            LastName,
                                            DeleteDate,
                                            Email,
                                            Fax,
                                            PostBox,
                                            Street,
                                            City,
                                            Province,
                                            Country)
            SELECT  IDdeleted = IdNo,
                    FirstName,
                    LastName,
                    DeleteDate = GETDATE(),
                    Email,
                    Fax,
                    PostBox,
                    Street,
                    City,
                    Province,
                    Country
            FROM Person 
            WHERE IdNo=@EmpID

            --Attempt Delete
                DELETE FROM [dbo].[Person]
                WHERE IdNo = @EmpID
                RETURN 1
            END

        ELSE 
            RETURN 0
    END


    GO
```

Comment: You are deleting the ID from the Person table then trying to select the values for the ID which was just deleted. Do the insert before the delete.

Comment: I think this might be better handled using a delete trigger.

Comment: @JacobH, I have tried it. but result is same?

Comment: Also, your `INSERT` is a bit messy. Try this instead (once you move it so it's *before* the `DELETE`): `INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog SELECT @EmpID, FirstName, LastName, getdate(), Email, Fax, PostBox, Street, City, Province, Country FROM Person WHERE IdNo = @EmpId`.

Comment: @P.Salmon  , Thanks for your support

Comment: @EdGibbs , I have tried it. but result is same?

Comment: Could you edit the question and post what `EMPLOYEE_DELETE` looks like now? My suggestion just tunes up the INSERT query. It's @P.Salmon's comment about putting the INSERT before the DELETE that's most important.

Comment: INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog(IDdeleted,
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            DeleteDate,
            Email,
            Fax,
            PostBox,
            Street,
            City,
            Province,
            Country)
    SELECT IDdeleted = IdNo,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      DeleteDate = GETDATE(),
      Email,
      Fax,
      PostBox,
      Street,
      City,
      Province,
      Country
    FROM Person 
    WHERE IdNo=@EmpID

    --Attempt Delete
     DELETE FROM [dbo].[Person]
     WHERE IdNo = @EmpID

Comment: @EdGibbs, done!

Comment: Just check my answer, it may give you another option to work with in the future. This works on SQL Server 2008 and above

Comment: @EdGibbs could you take a look at my answer? thanks

Comment: @Horacuix - nicely done; looks good to me. I'd forgotten about the `OUTPUT` keyword because I tend to use triggers for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

use output when deleting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Simple example:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.table1  
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar  
WHERE id = 4
```

In your case, work with this, it may contain an error

```
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[Person]              

    OUTPUT 
     DELETED.IdNo,
        DELETED.FirstName,
        DELETED.LastName,
        DeleteDate = GETDATE(),
        DELETED.Email,
        DELETED.Fax,
        DELETED.PostBox,
        DELETED.Street,
        DELETED.City,
        DELETED.Province,
        DELETED.Country
INTO EmployeeDeleteLog(IDdeleted,
                                FirstName,
                                LastName,
                                DeleteDate,
                                Email,
                                Fax,
                                PostBox,
                                Street,
                                City,
                                Province,
                                Country)

     WHERE IdNo = @EmpID
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed Procedure simply like this:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Employee_Delete](@EmpID int)
AS
BEGIN

```
IF [dbo].[countIDs](@EmpID) <> 1
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ID does not exist', 1, 1)
    RETURN 0
END



                INSERT INTO EmployeeDeleteLog(IDdeleted,
                                            FirstName,
                                            LastName,
                                            DeleteDate,
                                            Email,
                                            Fax,
                                            PostBox,
                                            Street,
                                            City,
                                            Province,
                                            Country)
            SELECT  IDdeleted = IdNo,
                    FirstName,
                    LastName,
                    DeleteDate = GETDATE(),
                    Email,
                    Fax,
                    PostBox,
                    Street,
                    City,
                    Province,
                    Country
            FROM Person 
            WHERE IdNo=@EmpID

    --Attempt Delete
                DELETE FROM [dbo].[Person]
                WHERE IdNo = @EmpID
```

END

GO

Finished!

Comment: you should wrap both operations in one transaction. Assume in the future some integrity referential constraint is added and delete failed, no insert would be done.